# KDE Connecting to Android on Ubuntu 22.04 fire wall settings

Tags: ufw

When the firewall is disabled, all works just fine. What ports must I permanently set to accept this connection and not compromise the security.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details what you mean by "to Android". Is it a connection via a USB cable? Any type of wireless connections? If wireless, what protocol do you intend to use?

Answer (score 1):

The [KDEConnect page on KDE's Userbase site](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#ufw) lists the ports that need to be opened to enable KDEConnect to operate:

> If your firewall is ufw, you can open the necessary ports with:
>
> `sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp`
>
> `sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp`
>
> `sudo ufw reload`